# How to filter out rows from multiple data frames that are inside a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a `dictionary` that contains many `dataframes`.

Sample data:

```
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame({"variable1":["a","a","b"]})
dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame({"variable1":["b","a","b"]})
dictionary = dict(zip(["dataframe1","dataframe2"],[dataframe1,dataframe2]))
```

What i would like to do, is to create a new `dictionary`, which will contain the `dataframe`s but it will exclude the rows from each dataframe for which `variable1=="a"`

The equivalent `R` command with `lists` would be

```
dictionary_new <- lapply(dictionary ,function(x){x[!variable1=="a",]})
```

How can i translate that to `Python` ?

Comment: @Bharathshetty For me it works. I am using `python 3.x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dict comprehension with [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). For exclude `a` need filter all values which are not `a`.

```
dictionary = {k:v.query('variable1!="a"') for k, v  in dictionary.items()}
```

Or:

```
dictionary = {k:v[v.variable1!="a"] for k, v  in dictionary.items()}
print (dictionary)


{'dataframe1':   variable1
2         b, 'dataframe2':   variable1
0         b
2         b}
```

Comment: works like a charm . thank you ! For my information, how could you extend it to add more than one condition ? So e.g. `variable2!="b"` ?

Comment: Sure, use `v[(v.variable1!="a") & (variable2!="b")]` or `v.query('variable1!="a" & variable2!="b"')`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
dictionary = {k:v.loc[v.variable1!="a",:] for k, v  in dictionary.items()}
```

It seems that @jezrael second suggestion is the fastest:

```
In [94]: timeit {k:v.query('variable1!="a"') for k, v  in dictionary.items()}
100 loops, best of 3: 1.83 ms per loop

In [95]: timeit {k:v[v.variable1!="a"] for k, v  in dictionary.items()}
1000 loops, best of 3: 533 µs per loop

In [96]: timeit {k:v.loc[v.variable1!="a",:] for k, v  in dictionary.items()}
1000 loops, best of 3: 593 µs per loop
```